# Is there any way I can read the notifcations that appear in my android home screen Notifications tab using java code?

Tags: android, notifications

The android home page displays notifications from different applications.
I would like to read those notifications using my program.
I tried to find information on that in forums and in android help but I was not able to find any information.

My actual goal is to read the notifications and if the notification is about an email from a certain person then I want to perform something in my application.(I use touch down for my email)
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible due to security reasons.

If you want to respond to events then you should try listening to them directly with intents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) and set it to listen to TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED events. This way, each time any of the application packages specified while configuring the AccessibilityService generates a new notification, the onAccessibilityEvent callback of your service will be called with all the information about the notification.